# C++ - Injecting DLL into remote process and displaying the information

Tags: c++, windows, hook

I am currently on Windows 10.

I've been spending a lot of time searching around for hook tutorials and I can't really seem to figure out how to do it, or a lot of times people will talk about hooks and will say "Well I'll tell you what hooking is, but won't show you how to do it." etc.

Anyways, here are some questions on what I want to do and maybe you can give me a quick mock up on how to.

- I know how to inject processes just fine, do I inject a .dll (With the HOOKPROC) into a remote process and call SetWindowHookEx or do I call SetWindowHookEx from my Win32 application?
- How would I retrieve the information from the remote process hookproc, would I use pipes?
- I want to use SH_SHELL to grab when the title bar when it repaints from a remote process and display it on my Win32 Application (kinda like a browser history)

Comment: Hooks are documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589.aspx), in exhaustive detail. I don't know what `SH_SHELL` is, so I cannot comment on it. The remainder of that 3rd (!) question sounds, like you are about to set yourself up for permanent failure, though.

Comment: Alright thanks I will give it a shot, and how do you mean by permanent failure?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds kinda shady, however you can just use an API call for this : [GetWindowText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I knew it was gonna come off as shady lol, but honestly speaking this knowledge isn't going into malware, I wanted to create a macro/keyboard recorder and was going to grab all this information to try and recreate the events as "real" as possible. (Because a lot of macros I have used are pretty inaccurate)